# Code blocks not allowed searchresults.aspx

Tags: 2013, search, error

I'm getting this error on a copy of our SharePoint 2013 site collection. I've tried unghosting searchresults.aspx, but it comes back with "Cannot revert to the site definition version of this file. It is a custom file and is not part of the site definition".

[image]

Comment: check this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/04/26/code-blocks-are-not-allowed-in-this-file-using-server-side-code-with-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I am currently having the same issue with my 2013 search site.
here is the  [article](http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2013/03/21/fixing-code-blocks-not-allowed.aspx) helped me.

I was still having the same error after following the article above. I have added the line below in the web.config

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true" />
```

After this, the error has disapeared. This is not a very good solution because it is allowing all pages to run server side scripts.

You can use this to limit the pages VirtualPath="~/_catalogs/masterpage/*"

Comment: In my case I was creating a new basic search center site from scratch. When I tried Enterprise Search Center I did not have this problem :)

Comment: This didn't work for me: `VirtualPath="~/_catalogs/masterpage/*"`

Comment: In SharePoint 2016 the wildcard approach is all that worked, exactly as it is written in the solution.  Make sure to include the "IncludeSubFolders" attribute

Answer (score 1):

As soon as it is "customized" (formerly known as "unghosted"), the reference to [the master page] for that site is in the database, not the file system. Without a change to web.config, code blocks are not allowed.

SharePoint disables the ability to create server-side script by default, you have to turn it on. You do that in the web.config file, in the **configuration/SharePoint/PageParserPaths configuration section**:

```
<PageParserPaths>

  <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/pages/test.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />

</PageParserPaths>
```

[Code-blocks are not allowed in this file: Using Server-Side Code with SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/04/26/code-blocks-are-not-allowed-in-this-file-using-server-side-code-with-sharepoint.aspx)

Comment: I'm still facing same issue even also i had specified above tag in web.config

Comment: The VirtualPath in this example should be the path to your custom master page that is giving the error. e.g. /_catalogs/masterpage/mycustom.master

Answer (score 0):

If there is a blue mark before your SearchResults.aspx,right click on it and click'Reset to Site Definition'

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the StackExchange standards. Please check [answer]. One-liners can be mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Tried both specific and wild card both did not work for me. What make it work was to reset the page to site definition.