# Code blocks are not allowed in this file in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using custom page layout for storing publishing pages.In that i had used ajax function: I had followed below links but no success:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120190/How-to-enable-code-blocks-in-Sharepoint-Works

[Code blocks not allowed searchresults.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136656/code-blocks-not-allowed-searchresults-aspx)

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<%#WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortalUrl"]%>/_layouts/15/Module/Ajax.aspx/GetScreen",
         data: JSON.stringify({ typeId: categoryId }),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {
         if (data.d != "") {
                 var imageUrl = data.d;
                 $(".listdetailbanner").css({ "background": "url(" + imageUrl + ") 
                 no-repeat center", "margin-bottom": "20px", "background-size": "cover" });
             } 
           },
           error: function () {
                    //alert("Error");
             }
      });
```

[image]

Comment: Allowing code blocks is a procedure to allow **server-side** code. Here you show us only JavaScript, i.e. **client-side** code... Do you have server-side code elsewhere in the file? Also: did you add the layout file or the final publishing page URL in the web.config file to allow it to execute code blocks?

Comment: i'm using this line in ajax url: "<%#WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortalUrl"]%>" becoz of this i'm getting error i think.

Comment: OK, I had missed it, sorry! That's indeed the "unsafe" server-side code, OK :) Now, what URL did you put in the web.config? The publishing page URL or the layout URL?

Comment: site collection url "http://comp-pcname:11111/"

Comment: With a star `*` like this `VirtualPath="/*"`?

Comment: yes i tried that also still getting same error

Comment: Can you please post your `SafeMode` section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26065/discussion-between-evariste-and-light).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="250" AllowPageLevelTrace="false"> 
 <PageParserPaths> 
  <PageParserPath VirtualPath="~/_catalogs/masterpage/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" /> 
 </PageParserPaths> 
</SafeMode>
```

or:

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="250" AllowPageLevelTrace="false"> 
 <PageParserPaths> 
  <PageParserPath VirtualPath="~/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" /> 
 </PageParserPaths> 
</SafeMode>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the virtual path of a .aspx file which is inside a folder of template\feature folder? Above code is added, but issue not fixed